# How to resize android.media.Image

Tags: android, android-image

How can you resize an `android.media.Image` on the fly?

The `Image` I am working with is small, which is OK for the recording, but I need to temporarily stretch the image to a larger scale for analysis.

```java
Image image = mImageReader.acquireNextImage();

// ...
// Resize image to a larger size in memory. Quality is not of a concern.
// ...

image.close();
```

Any ideas would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

First convert your image into bitmap with this method `convertImageToBitmap()` then resize the bitmap with `getResizedBitmap()` method given below. i hope this will help you.

**Convert Bitmap with:**

```
private Bitmap convertImageToBitmap(Image image) {

    ByteBuffer buffer = image.getPlanes()[0].getBuffer();
    byte[] bytes = new byte[buffer.capacity()];
    buffer.get(bytes);
    Bitmap bitmapImage = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bytes, 0, bytes.length, null);

    return bitmapImage;
}
```

**Resize Bitmap with:**

```
public Bitmap getResizedBitmap(Bitmap image, int maxSize) {
    int width = 50;
    int height = 50;  // image.getHeight()

    float bitmapRatio = (float) width / (float) height;
    if (bitmapRatio > 1) {
        width = maxSize;
        height = (int) (width / bitmapRatio);
    } else {
        height = maxSize;
        width = (int) (height * bitmapRatio);
    }
    return Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(image, width, height, true);
}
```

Comment: `convertImageToBitmap` is returning `null`. I can confirm the image is valid, and bytes has a length. Also, the input Image is YUV, so this is only grabbing 1 color profile no?

Comment: This doesn't produce an `android.media.Image` in the end, it results in an `android.graphics.Bitmap`

Comment: Good answer. I'd like to add that you can call .compress() on the returned (scaled) bitmap, providing a ByteArrayOutputStream(), then call .toByteArray() on this to get the raw JPEG file data.